# Chrome/jQuery Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (Function Loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i'm quite puzzled how this is happening but my jQuery is somehow causing some kind of conflict and racking up the memory use to over 1.2gbs for that one tab.

```
<script>
function homeFader(){
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $("#homeBannerContainer").fadeOut(3000);
            $(".bannerRightUnicef").animate({marginLeft:"457px"},0);
        }, 3000);

        setTimeout(function() { 
            $("#homeBannerContainerTwo").fadeOut(3000);
        }, 8000);

        setTimeout(function() { 
            $(".bannerRightUnicef").animate({marginLeft:"0px"},1000);
        }, 9000);

        setTimeout(function() { 
            $("#homeBannerContainer").fadeIn(3000,function() {  
                $("#homeBannerContainerTwo").css("display","block");
            });
        }, 13000);

        setInterval(function() { homeFader(); },15000);


}


$(document).ready(function() {
    homeFader();
});

</script>
```

Any solution to this?

Greatly appreciated

~Matt

Comment: It doesn't look like there are any obvious infinite loops in your code. Could you post a demo including the relevant HTML and CSS on www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Try `setInterval(homeFader,15000);`

Comment: Also the `setInterval(homeFader,15000)` call should not be within the `homeFader`, if you want to place it inside the `homeFader` then use `setTimeout(homeFader,15000);` else you place `setInterval(homeFader,15000)` in the dom ready handler

Comment: Thank you @ArunPJohny , that worked like a charm! No lag at all and it's staying under the 100mb threshold when operating, which is great. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments use `setTimeout()` in the `homeFader` instead of `setInterval`

```
function homeFader() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#homeBannerContainer").fadeOut(3000);
        $(".bannerRightUnicef").animate({
            marginLeft: "457px"
        }, 0);
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#homeBannerContainerTwo").fadeOut(3000);
    }, 8000);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".bannerRightUnicef").animate({
            marginLeft: "0px"
        }, 1000);
    }, 9000);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#homeBannerContainer").fadeIn(3000, function () {
            $("#homeBannerContainerTwo").css("display", "block");
        });
    }, 13000);

    setTimeout(homeFader, 15000);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    homeFader();
});
```

or call setInterval like

```
function homeFader() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#homeBannerContainer").fadeOut(3000);
        $(".bannerRightUnicef").animate({
            marginLeft: "457px"
        }, 0);
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#homeBannerContainerTwo").fadeOut(3000);
    }, 8000);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".bannerRightUnicef").animate({
            marginLeft: "0px"
        }, 1000);
    }, 9000);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#homeBannerContainer").fadeIn(3000, function () {
            $("#homeBannerContainerTwo").css("display", "block");
        });
    }, 13000);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    homeFader();
    setInterval(homeFader, 15000);
});
```